# Geofencing does not work in real scenario

Tags: android, geofencing

ive been trying the sample code provided by Google at http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html
i cannot get the notification of entering/exiting geofence even though i have move into the region physically.

However when I tried to run the Google Map App to see my location, the geofence notification comes in.

I have also tried it with mock location, everything is working fine with mock location.

The devices i tried with are:
Samsung Galaxy S4 (OS version 4.4.2)
Sony Xperia Z2 (OS version 4.4.2)

My question is, do i have to do anything to get the location service running so that my app can get the real time location, without having to run Google Map App?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about your phone's setting? In the "Locations" settings, is the accuracy set to "High Accuracy"?

Comment: @alpinescrambler yes i have set the accuracy to "High Accuracy"

Comment: I installed this demo into my S4 phone and live tested it. I works "OK", but sometimes, it doesn't but I am taking the tube (intermittent signal)

Comment: @alpinescrambler may i know what is the radius you set? and did run the Google Map App during your testing?

Comment: I've used like 500 meters. And it does seem to "help" if yiu opened other apps that uses Location services.

Comment: @alpinescrambler the radius i was using is 200 meters, maybe that is too small, gonna try it again when im home.. Ya it does.. when i opened Google Map, i got the notification..